# Best way to determine referrering domain in PHP?

Tags: php, http, referrer

I've got some code I want to show on a PHP site only to visitors from Twitter.com.  What's the best way to do this?

Comment: explain a bit more? what do you mean visitors from twitter.like they came right from twitter or what.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, if you're going to be outputting different content depending on the referrer, you should also do

```
header( 'Vary: Referer' );
```

so that browser and proxies will know that the content may vary depending on the referrer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

PHP Code:

```
<?PHP 
   $visitor_url = "twitter";
   $uri = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
   $check_visitor = strpos(strtolower($uri['host']), $visitor_url);
   if($findme);

   if($check_visitor !== false) {       
     //do something
   }

?>
```

Comment: No, you have to lower two operands of `==` operator for case insensitivity. Fix it to `strtolower($uri['host']) == 'twitter'`.

Comment: The hostname is not going to be `"twitter"`; it might be `"twitter.com"`, or possibly something else (like `"t.co"`) if the links go through a redirector (or several!).

Comment: then you have to use explode($uri['host'], ".")[0];

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
    $tmp = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];

    $result = strpos($tmp, "twitter.com/");
    if($result === false) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
        exit;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['from_twitter']=true;
    }

    //show content
}
```

Comment: What happens if the referer_url is twitter.com.cn or .uk ?

Comment: if((strpos($tmp, "twitter.com/") === false)||(strpos($tmp, "twitter.com.cn/") === false)) {

Comment: then you have to write "IF"s for all domain extensions.. It is better ,if you check for twitter only, not the extensions.